# Artifactory has lost track of local artifacts

Tags: artifactory

I'm using Artifactory OSS 4.1.0 and Java 1.8.0_51.

When I try to download one of my local artifacts from the Artifactory web interface, I get this:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 500,
    "message" : "Could not process download request: Binary provider has no content for 'bab1c4e18f6c5edfb65b2503a388dea2fed0deb8'"
  } ]
}
```

But I found this file in my Artifactory data area: `./files/ba/bab1c4e18f6c5edfb65b2503a388dea2fed0deb8`, and upon further inspection it is the WAR file I tried to download.

I've come across other people on the web with the same error message, but their issue was with caching external artifacts, and their workaround was to delete the cache.

Does anyone have an idea what's going on and how I can fix the problem? BTW, I did stop and restart our Artifactory server, but with no noticeable difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artifactory doesn't store the binaries under `./files` directory, but under `$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/data/filestore`.

It looks like you had a symbolic link from the `files` directory to the `filestore` directory and this link was deleted.

Comment: Thanks, JBaruch! That wasn't the exact problem, but it pointed me in the right direction. In my case the `etc/storage.properties` file's `binary.provider.filesystem.dir` property was no longer pointing to the `files` directory. Updating it fixed the problem.

Comment: Right, that too. Completely forgot that it's a property now.