# Binary provider has no content

Tags: artifactory

I had to take over responsiblity over Artifactory suddently (responsible employee left), I've never worked with it before, I've spent the day trying to learn the product and figure things out.

**Problem Context:**

Artifactory deployed on VM in Azure (ubuntu), mounted disk has artifactory deployed on it (OSS 6.0.2 rev 60002900)
Disk got full = application crashed.

I increased disk size, repartioned and re-mounted and the artifactory came up again - but now getting the following error message in the browser:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 500,
    "message" : "Could not process download request: Binary provider has no content for 'b8135c33f045ab2cf45ae4d256148d66373a0c89'"
  } ]
}
```

I have searched a bit and found various possible solutions.

This one:[Artifactory has lost track of local artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36024671/artifactory-has-lost-track-of-local-artifacts)

which seems to be the most promesing since the context of our issue is similar, but I don't see those paths - i.e. I do see the `filestore` and everything in it, but not other paths/files mentioned in the conversation.

I also found this: https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-6324 but again not finding the paths in our deployment.

To the best of my understanding it seems that if I somehow "reinstall" the filestore and/or database things should work? 
Is there a clear manual, or something basic I'm missing? I'd like to avoid having to isntall everything from scratch.

Any help would be most appreciated as our entire Dev org is not sort of blocked and trying to workaround locally somehow until this is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I am a JFrog Support Engineer and we saw your issue, we will contact you on other channels in order to help you resolve this issue.

Edit:
After reaching out, we found that this issue was caused by a specific file that was corrupted/missing from your filestore, and after deleting this file and re-pulling it the issue was solved.

To further elaborate on this issue and what can cause it:
Artifactory implements a checksum based storage. All files deployed/cached in Artifactory are renamed to their checksum value and saved in the filestore, and Artifactory creates a pointer in the DataBase containing the name, checksum and some other properties of the file. This allows for a more efficient storage since all files are only saved once in the filestore but can have multiple pointers in the DataBase (in various locations inside Artifactory - different repositories or archives even).
When a file gets corrupted in the filestore or even deleted (without deleting it from Artifactory), this issue can manifest, since there is still a pointer to this file in Artifactory's DataBase but the binary itself does not exist in the filestore.
This issue can be caused by various causes such as connection issues with the NFS/S3/other types of storage, files being corrupted or deleted from the filestore, etc.

Another edit:
You can also use a [user plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins) called "[filestoreIntegrity](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/filestore/filestoreIntegrity)" that can go through all the pointers to files in your DataBase and checks if they exist in the filestore. This way you can know if there are corrupted or missing files and fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Today we started getting this error on all artifacts in our Artifactory (version 7.55.13, HA mode, in Docker). This followed another incident, where we had to move the entire HA share file server to a dedicated datastore because of disk latency issues. Nothing else was changed with the file server, but I guess this broke the mounted share directory on the Artifactory VM. Artifactory also seems very sensitive about the permissions on this mounted share. We managed to solve it by simply unmounting and remounting the HA share directories with correct permissions.

I vaguely recall having done the same thing a year or two ago, possibly following some other issue with the file server. So I guess one thing to check if you come across this error, is if it affects *all* artifacts, or only a few. If everything is affected, checking the HA share mount is probably a good place to start.